# Using calculated columns to create a button for each list item that launches a Javascript function passing column values as the parameter

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

**The Issue**

I have struggled create a calculated column in my SharePoint list that renders a button with an onclick event to start a javascript function while passing two column values from the list item.

After searching the internet high and low for answers, I am convinced that this may not be possible with calculated columns. **Is this even possible?**

**The SharePoint list**

The user will select the "Active" button from the list item row and the Javascript function should start

[image: My SharePoint list]

**The Javascript code to be started from the "Active" button**

The button should create the following code for each list item:

```
<input type='button' value='Active' onclick='examplefunction(Title,Status)'/>")
```

For the first list item in the row this would be:

```
<input type='button' value='Active' onclick='examplefunction("Title 1","Active")'/>")
```

To correctly render the html, the following calculated column formula is used (formatted as a number):

```
=CONCATENATE("<input type='button' value='Active' onclick=","examplefunction('",Title,"','",Status,"')"," />")
```

**The Javascript for the function (via a Content Editor webpart)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function examplefunction(Title,Status) {
alert(Title);
alert(Status);
}
</script>
```

**My results**

I have tried countless times to write and rewrite the calculated column formula (with and without using CONCATENATE) but I cannot pass the title or status column values.

I usually get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

**If this is possible, how would I write the formula?** in the limited examples available online, I have not been able to replicate that success.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution! For those with the same problem please checkout:

http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Danny from Viewmaster has a great page on HTML Calculated Columns and Javascript! I was able modify his example formula code to solve my problem:

```
="<input type='button' value='Active' onclick=""examplefunction( '"
 & Title
 & "', '"
 & Status
 & "'); "">"
```

Thanks Danny.

Comment: Yes, the *need-to-know* is those double-double-quotes **""** so the Formula will output a single-double-quote **"** ; you can then use single quotes in the JavaScript part. Be sure to read all the Pros and Cons on that page: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Comment: Note that with Microsoft Modern Experiences they have disabled HTML/JS injecting using this Calculated Column trick. So this all only works on 2007...till 2016/SPonline in CLASSIC mode